# Detect incoming video call in android

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to know how to detect an incoming Video call on android device? Actually there are lots of documentation on detecting incoming phone calls but I couldn't find any information on detecting incoming native video calls in android?
I found source code of Samsung `Phone.apk` and find this method `localConnection.getCall().isVideoCall()` or `this.mPhone.getForegroundCall().isVideoCall()` that detect VideoCall
but this method needs import `com.android.internal.telephony.*` and this is not allowed for third party applications.
I think to call this classes need use reflection.
So may you let me know on this?

and excuse me i cant speak English very well but i think you understand me.

Answer (score 3):

FIrst of all your english is Good, so dont worry.

Yes if you think accessing telephony apis let you do this, then here is an example which uses internal telephony apis directly from user space applicatoin..

[Auto_answer app using internalTelephony by reflection](http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Answer (score 2):

Like @Ankit is saying you can use iTelephony just like in the [AutoAnswer](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer%253Fstate%253Dclosed) code but you have to add a line to [this](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl) file (that you have to put on your project) :

```
/**
 * Return TRUE, if current call is video call
 * First active call has priority
 */
boolean isVideoCall();
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
private Boolean isVideoCall(Context context) {

    Class<?> c;
    try {
        c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(manager);

    return telephonyService.isVideoCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        telephonyService = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
return false;
    }
}
```

Just detect the incoming call like the code that is on auto-answer and then do this check to see if it is video.